# Custom Odoo Qweb view

Tags: xml, xpath, odoo, odoo-12

I'm trying to customize a view in Odoo V12 adding with "xpath" expression some content but it's not working.

This is the place where the content needs to be added.
[image]

I'm using the next code for inheriting the template and for making the changes.

```
<record id="education_calendar_website_event_template" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Education calendar website event</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="website_event.index" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="/t[1]/t[1]/div[1]/div[1]" position="inside">
            <div id="website_calendar_events" style="display: none;">
                <ul>
                    <t t-foreach="event_ids" t-as="event">
                        <li>
                            <p class="website_event_data" id="e_data_1">
                                <t t-esc="event.id" />
                            </p>
                        </li>
                    </t>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I tried the next expression too and not working:
- //div[@id='oe_structure_website_event_index_1']

Anyone knows how to inherit data and modify/add existing templates?
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `template` tag and specify the id of the template to alter with the `inherit_id` attribute.

```
<template id="event_ids" inherit_id="website_event.index">
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='oe_structure_website_event_index_1']" position="inside">
        <div id="website_calendar_events">
            <ul>
                <t t-foreach="event_ids" t-as="event">
                    <li>
                        <p class="website_event_data" id="e_data_1">
                            <t t-esc="event.id"/>
                        </p>
                    </li>
                </t>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```